# Send Html Mail in Console application

Tags: .net, email, c#-4.0

i have created a console application to send mail now i have html templates
i am getting data from database according to user now how to bind this data in html.
my code is

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get All User
        var userList = BLLMailAlert.GetAllSubscribedUser();
        // Send UserID as Parameter and Find Tenders For Users
        foreach (var user in userList)
        {
            BLLMailAlert.GetAllTenderForPaidUser(user.UserID);

            // For Each AlertId Find Template Name and EmailId
            foreach (var usr in userList)
            {
                var detail = BLLMailAlert.GetUserAllDetail(usr.AlertID);

                // According to TemplateName FIND Template and Write Tender in that Template
                switch (usr.UserTypeTemplate.TemplateType.TemplateTypeName)
                {
                    case "TemplateForPaidUser.htm":
                    {
                        // Send Template in Mail To Each User
                        var fromEmail = string.Empty;
                        var toEmail = string.Empty;
                        toEmail = usr.Email;
                        fromEmail = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adminmail"]);
                        const string TemplatePath = "[Path to resource]";
                        var mailContent = new StreamReader(TemplatePath).ReadToEnd();
                        mailContent += detail;
                        BLLMailAlert.SendTenderAlert(fromEmail, toEmail, mailContent);
                    }

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //function to send mail
    // I have Class named Mail which i am using to send mail
    public static bool SendTenderAlert(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string mailContent)
    {
        try
        {
            var currentDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date;
            Mail.SendHtmlMail(fromEmail, toEmail, "TenderKhabar | Fresh Tenders Of |" + currentDate, mailContent);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.Replace`. Everybody does that. It may not sound elegant, but it has many advantages

1. You don't need to know about document formats, you just replace strings
2. Template format may change, but your code stays same.

In my company we generally use curly brackets `Dear <strong>{Customer.Name}</strong>,` but it can be `Dear <strong>$(Customer.Name)</strong>,`

In one case, I had to write code `if`s and `for`s for templates, and I've used regex and string replace.

Comment: A note for future readers: if you do this (BTW why to avoid to use T4 Text Templates?) do not forget to escape strings (if, for example, they come from user input they may contain characters forbidden in HTML).